# r grep by regex - finding a string that contains a sub string exactly one once

Tags: regex, r

I am using R in Ubuntu, and trying to go over list of files, some of them i need and some of them i don't need,

I try to get the one's i need by finding a sub string in them, that need to appear exactly once,

i am using the function grep, that i found here [grep function in r](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/grep.html)

and using the regex rules that i found here [regex rules](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

and when taking the simple example

```
a <- c("a","aa") 
grep("a{1}", a)
```

i would expect to get only the strings that contain "a" exactly one time, and instead of it i get both of them.

when i use the 2 instead of 1, i do get the wanted result of one strings (the one that contains "aa")

i can't use $ because this is not the end of the word for the words i need, for example i need to take those two words "germ-pass.tab", "germ-pass_germ-pass.tab" and return only the first that contains "germ-pass" once and once only

i cant use ^a because i don't need words such as "aca"

Thanks.

Comment: `grep` looks for a pattern inside your `string`, you need to add to the pattern that the `"a"` is followed by not a : `"a[^a]"`

Comment: i found that we can use {} to find exact number of occurrences, i am trying to use a simple regex, for something a bit more complex then finding "a"... trying to find out what i am doing wrong with {}

Comment: the thing is, in "aa", there is the pattern "a", with exactly one occurence. It just happens to be followed by another "a"...

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. Both of your examples contain `a` once. The first one won't match `a{2}`.

Comment: @sebastian-c but the entire idea of {1} or {,1} is "not more than once"... you would expect it not to return "aa"

Comment: `{1}` means *"The preceding item is matched exactly 1 time"* not "not more than"

Comment: `stringi::stri_count()`

Comment: @hrbrmstr thanks, this is beautiful, pls post it as answer!

Comment: btw, why the down vote?

Comment: Not sure who did the down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `stringi::stri_count`:

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

# simulate some data
set.seed(1492)
(map_chr(1:10, function(i) {
  paste0(sample(letters, sample(10:30), replace=TRUE), collapse="")
}) -> strings)

## [1] "jdpcypoizdzvfzs"               "gyvcljnfmrzmdmkufq"           
## [3] "xqwrmnklbixnccwyaiadrsxn"      "bwbenawcwvdevmjfvs"           
## [5] "ytzwnpkuromfbklfsdnbwwnlrw"    "wclxpzftqgwxyetpsuslgohcdenuj"
## [7] "czkhanefss"                    "mxsrqrackxvimcxqcqsditrou"    
## [9] "ysqshvzjjmwes"                 "yzawyoqxqxiasensorlenafcbk" 

# How many "w"s in each string?
stri_count_regex(strings, "w{1}")

## [1] 0 0 2 3 4 2 0 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

As I said in comments, `grep` looks for a pattern inside your string and there is indeed "a" (or "a{1}", which is the same for `grep`) in "aa". You need to add to the pattern that the "a" is followed by not a : `"a[^a]"`:

```
grep("a[^a]", c("aa", "ab"), value=TRUE)
#[1] "ab"
```

*EDIT*

Considering your specific problem, it seems you can try by the "opposite" : filter out the strings that contains more than one occurence of the pattern, using a "capture" of the pattern:

```
!grepl("(ab).+\\1", c("ab.t", "ab-ab.t"))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE

!grepl("(ab).*\\1", c("ab", "ab-ab","ab-cc-ab", "abab"))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The brackets permit to capture the pattern (here `ab` but it can be any regex), the `.*` is for "anything" zero or more times and the `\\1` asks for a repeat of the captured pattern

Comment: no, this is not good for me, it is possible to have "aca" this is a word that i need to be able to filter out. i don't need this word @Cath

Comment: @captainshai see my edit, it may better fulfill your needs

Comment: !grepl("(ab).\\1", c("ab", "ab-ab","ab-cc-ab"))
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE        this is also problematic...

Comment: @captainshai then you need to change the `.` to a regex that corresponds to what you have in your file names, here : `!grepl("(ab).+\\1", c("ab", "ab-ab","ab-cc-ab"))`, I edited accordingly

Comment: still does not work, is there anyway to use {1} for finding strings that contain the sub string exactly once?

Comment: @captainshai it works on all the examples you provided, could you try to give an example that is representative of your data ?

Comment: *is there anyway to use {1} for finding strings that contain the sub string exactly once* - No. More: `{1}` is redundant and should be removed from any pattern.

Comment: here is an example that will produce unwanted results: !grepl("(ab).+\\1", c("abab", "ab-ab","ab-cc-ab")) , i allready gave an example to my wanted application in the OP edit.

Comment: @captainshai see my edit. that's exactly what I meant by "a representative example" = something that covers all real life cases...

Answer (score 3):

## Detecting strings with `a` but not `aa`

You can use the following TRE regex:

```
^[^a]*a[^a]*$
```

It matches the start of the string (`^`), 0+ chars other than `a` (`[^a]*`), an `a`, again 0+ non-'a's and the end of string (`$`). See this [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/NCibmr):

```
a <- c("aca","cac","a", "abab", "ab-ab", "ab-cc-ab")
grep("^[^a]*a[^a]*$", a, value=TRUE)
## => [1] "cac" "a"
```

## Finding Whole Word Containing `a` but not `aa`

If you need to match *words* that have one `a` only, but not two or more `a`s inside in any location.

Use this PCRE regex:

```
\b(?!\w*a\w*a)\w*a\w*\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJ3aF3/1).

**Explanation**:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!\w*a\w*a)` - a negative lookahead failing the match if there are 0+ word chars, `a`, 0+ word chars and `a` again right after the word boundary
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars
- `a` - an `a`
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars
- `\b` - trailing word boundary.

**NOTE**: Since `\w` matches letters, digits and underscores, you might want to change it to `\p{L}` or `[^\W\d_]` (only matches letters).

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/JLI6rz):

```
a <- c("aca","cac","a")
grep("\\b(?!\\w*a\\w*a)\\w*a\\w*\\b", a, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
## => [1] "cac" "a"
```

Comment: sorry, not a standalone word, but a part of a word... for an example, from the words c("aca","cac","a") i need only the last two

Comment: stribizew i can't use a \\b, this is not guarantied to be the beginning of the word

Comment: Remove it then. Could you share a case where my regex fails to fetch what you need?

Comment: Does it mean you need to match whole *strings*? Like [`^[^a]*a[^a]*$`](https://ideone.com/NCibmr)?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're after strings with one `a` and no more, regardless where in the string. While `stringi` can accomplish the task, a base solution would be:

```
s <- c("a", "aa", "aca", "", "b", "ba", "ab")

m <- gregexpr("a", s)
s[lengths(regmatches(s, m)) == 1]

[1] "a"  "ba" "ab"
```

Alternatively, a regex-lite approach:

```
s[vapply(strsplit(s, ""), function(x) sum(x == "a") == 1, logical(1))]
[1] "a"  "ba" "ab"
```

Answer (score 1):

we can try with `^` and `$` to make sure that there is only a single 'a' in the string

```
grep("^a$", a)
#[1] 1
```

It is not clear what the OP wanted.

Comment: i can't use $, this is not the end of the words that i am looking for... but up vote for the answer still...

Comment: @captainshai  Please use an example that represents the problem

Comment: i added the relevant example, pls explain what you mean by "OP"

Comment: @captainshai  I meant the original poster

Comment: thanks. the answer is great but i am afraid it does not fit my need here...

Answer (score 0):

In *base* you can find a *string that contains a sub string exactly once* when you remove the sub-string with `gsub` and test if the remaining string lenght is equal to the searched sub string:

```
s <- c("a", "aa", "aca", "", "b", "ba", "ab", "cac", "abab", "ab-ab", NA)
ss  <- "a" #Substring to find exactly once

nchar(s) - nchar(gsub(ss, "", s)) == nchar(ss)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA
```

or you count the hits of `gregexpr`

```
sapply(gregexpr(ss, s), function(x) sum(x>0)) == 1
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA
```

or as @sebastian-c already mentioned

```
lengths(regmatches(s, gregexpr(ss, s))) == 1
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

or with two `grepl` one asking if the sub string is present one time the other if it is there two times:

```
!grepl("(.*a){2}", s) & grepl("a", s)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

or the same explained in one *regex*, where `(?!(.*a){2})` is a non consuming (zero-width) negative lookahead

```
grepl("^(?!(.*a){2}).*a.*$", s, perl=TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

or more general, in case you want to change it to find the sub-string exactly n times

```
!grepl("(.*a){2}", s) & grepl("(.*a){1}", s)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

grepl("^(?!(.*a){2})(.*a){1}.*$", s, perl=TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

In case you are looking only for *one character* you can use the solution form @wiktor-stribiżew

```
grepl("^[^a]*a[^a]*$", s)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```